# Visual Studio Community problem in Unity 3d, asking to upgrade but I am using free version

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Image :

[image]

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 with Unity 3d, but after few days I got this issue, what to do?

Comment: It simply says your 30 days of the trial has been ended and therefore you need to sign in.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign-in using a Microsoft Account (@outlook.com, @live.com, @hotmail.com) or any email address registered as Microsoft Account.

Or, click on "**Create one!**"

2. Then click on "**Check for an updated license**"

Everything will be okay.

Comment: now that error is solved but intelligence with unity not working

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, I just had to log into my account and it started working again.

Comment: Have you tried adding an account using a Microsoft account?